# What's the time to release the image of the imageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I create a `UIImage` and set to the property of the imageView, then I release the currentImg,
whether there is a problem in these code ?

```
self.currentContentImv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
UIImage *currentImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"whatever..."]];
self.currentContentImv.image = currentImg;
[currentImg release];
```

Sometimes it will be crash, so in this situation how could I write it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you sure it's crashing in this code? Can you post a stack trace from a crash?

Comment: It crashed on the ipad of my friends, He told me that, so I'm not sure 100%. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are releasing the `currentImg` properly.  In this circumstance, you may want to create the `UIImage` using the static `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` method.  This will automatically add currentImg to the autorelease pool.

```
UIImage *currentImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: @"whatever..."];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `autorelease`.

```
UIImage *currentImg = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"whatever..."] autorelease];
```

Also, you should read over Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).